# Am Chart - how to display all values in X -axis?

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts

I would like to ask, how can i display all number values in axis X in chart?

Now is are displayed only values 1,4,8,12 and would like to display all numbers, it means 1..12 in X axis (See image).

Thanks for any help.[image]

Answer (score 5):

Within your "categoryAxis" settings make sure you add **"autoGridCount": false** and also **"gridCount": 12**.  Your settings sound look something like this.

```
"categoryAxis": {
    "gridPosition": "start",
    "labelRotation": 45,
    "minorGridEnabled": true,
    /* ENSURE 2 LINES BELOW ARE ADDED */
    "autoGridCount": false,
    "gridCount": 12
},
```

I have used 12 based on your example but this should be the total number of columns you have in your chart if different.